# How to install pyqt5 and how to run pyqt5 in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to use pyqt5 in pycharm, but I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5' error.

I wonder if pyqt5 is not installed and can not be run normally, so I tried reinstalling it by doing pip uninstall pyqt5 && pip install pyqt5 from the anaconda prompt, and then pip list to see if it was properly installed.
And when you install pyqt5 by pip install pyqt5 in the anconda prompt,

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

spyder 5.2.2 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.

pyqt5-tools 5.15.4.3.2 requires pyqt5==5.15.4, but you have pyqt5 5.12.3 which is incompatible.

pyqt5-plugins 5.15.4.2.2 requires pyqt5==5.15.4, but you have pyqt5 5.12.3 which is incompatible
```

this sentence appears at the end. Is there a problem installing?

This is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import logging.handlers
import time
from pandas import DataFrame

is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
if is_64bits:
    print('64bit')
else:
    print('32bit')

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s|%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(asctime)s > %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("crumbs")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL = 0.2


class Openapi(QAxWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print("openapi __name__:", __name__)
        super().__init__()
        self._create_open_api_instance()
        self._set_signal_slots()
        self.comm_connect()
        self.account_info()

    def _opt10081(self, rqname, trcode):

        ohlcv_cnt = self._get_repeat_cnt(trcode, rqname)

        
        for i in range(ohlcv_cnt):
            date = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "date")
            open = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "market price")
            high = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "high price")
            low = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "low price")
            close = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "current price")
            volume = self._get_comm_data(trcode, rqname, i, "trading volume")

            self.ohlcv['date'].append(date)
            self.ohlcv['open'].append(int(open))
            self.ohlcv['high'].append(int(high))
            self.ohlcv['low'].append(int(low))
            self.ohlcv['close'].append(int(close))
            self.ohlcv['volume'].append(int(volume))

    def _receive_tr_data(self, screen_no, rqname, trcode, record_name, next, unused1, unused2, unused3, unused4):
        # print("_receive_tr_data!!!")
        # print(rqname, trcode, next)
        if next == '2':
            self.remained_data = True
        else:
            self.remained_data = False

        if rqname == "opt10081_req":

            self._opt10081(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opw00001_req":
            # print("opw00001_req!!!")
            # print("Get an de_deposit!!!")
            self._opw00001(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opw00018_req":
            # print("opw00018_req!!!")
            # print("Get the possessed item !!!!")
            self._opw00018(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opt10074_req":
            # print("opt10074_req!!!")
            # print("Get the profit")
            self._opt10074(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opw00015_req":
            # print("opw00015_req!!!")
            # print("deal list!!!!")
            self._opw00015(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opt10076_req":
            # print("opt10076_req")
            # print("chegyul list!!!!")
            self._opt10076(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opt10073_req":
            # print("opt10073_req")
            # print("Get today profit !!!!")
            self._opt10073(rqname, trcode)
        elif rqname == "opt10080_req":
            # print("opt10080_req!!!")
            # print("Get an de_deposit!!!")
            self._opt10080(rqname, trcode)

        try:
            self.tr_event_loop.exit()
        except AttributeError:
            pass


    def get_total_data(self, code, start):

        self.ohlcv = {'date': [], 'open': [], 'high': [], 'low': [], 'close': [], 'volume': []}
        self.set_input_value("item code", code)
        self.set_input_value("base date", start)
        self.set_input_value("Classification of revised stock price", 1)
        self.comm_rq_data("opt10081_req", "opt10081", 0, "0101")


        while self.remained_data == True:
            # time.sleep(TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL)
            self.set_input_value("item code", code)
            self.set_input_value("base date", start)
            self.set_input_value("Classification of revised stock price", 1)
            self.comm_rq_data("opt10081_req", "opt10081", 2, "0101")

        time.sleep(0.2)
        
        if len(self.ohlcv) == 0:
            return []

        if self.ohlcv['date'] == '':
            return []

        df = DataFrame(self.ohlcv, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], index=self.ohlcv['date'])

        return df


    def get_one_day_option_data(self, code, start, option):

        self.ohlcv = {'date': [], 'open': [], 'high': [], 'low': [], 'close': [], 'volume': []}

        self.set_input_value("item code", code)

        self.set_input_value("base date", start)

        self.set_input_value("Classification of revised stock price", 1)

        self.comm_rq_data("opt10081_req", "opt10081", 0, "0101")

        if self.ohlcv['date'] == '':
            return False

        df = DataFrame(self.ohlcv, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'], index=self.ohlcv['date'])
        if option == 'open':
            return df.iloc[0, 0]
        elif option == 'high':
            return df.iloc[0, 1]
        elif option == 'low':
            return df.iloc[0, 2]
        elif option == 'close':
            return df.iloc[0, 3]
        elif option == 'volume':
            return df.iloc[0, 4]
        else:
            return False

    def multi_601_get_ohlcv_daliy_craw(self, code, code_name, start):
        self.ohlcv = {'index': [], 'date': [], 'open': [], 'high': [], 'low': [], 'close': [], 'volume': []}

        self.set_input_value("item code", code)
        self.set_input_value("base date", start)
        self.set_input_value("Classification of revised stock price", 1)
        self.comm_rq_data("opt10081_req", "opt10081", 0, "0101")
        time.sleep(0.2)

        if self.ohlcv['date'][0] == '':
            return []

        if self.ohlcv['date'] == '':
            return []

        df = DataFrame(self.ohlcv, columns=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])

        return df

    def account_info(self):
        account_number = self.get_login_info("ACCNO")
        self.account_number = account_number.split(';')[0]
        logger.debug("account unmber: " + self.account_number)

    def get_login_info(self, tag):
        try:
            ret = self.dynamicCall("GetLoginInfo(QString)", tag)
            time.sleep(TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL)
            return ret
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def _create_open_api_instance(self):
        try:
            self.setControl("KHOPENAPI.KHOpenAPICtrl.1")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def _set_signal_slots(self):
        try:
            self.OnEventConnect.connect(self._event_connect)
            self.OnReceiveTrData.connect(self._receive_tr_data)
            self.OnReceiveMsg.connect(self._receive_msg)
            
            self.OnReceiveChejanData.connect(self._receive_chejan_data)


        except Exception as e:
            is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
            if is_64bits:
                logger.critical('This Anaconda is 64bit. Execute 32bit')
            else:
                logger.critical(e)

    def _receive_chejan_data(self, gubun, item_cnt, fid_list):
        print("_receive_chejan_data!!!")
        print("gubun!!!")
        print(gubun)

  
        if gubun == "0":
            print("in conclusion data!!!!!")
            order_num = self.get_chejan_data(9203)
            code_name_temp = self.get_chejan_data(302)

            code_name = self.change_format3(code_name_temp)

            code = self.codename_to_code(code_name)

            chegyul_fail_amount_temp = self.get_chejan_data(902)
            order_gubun = self.get_chejan_data(905)
            purchase_price = self.get_chejan_data(10)

            if code != False and code != "" and code != 0 and code != "0":
                if chegyul_fail_amount_temp != "":
                    if self.is_all_item_db_check(code) == False:
                        print("This is new")
                        if chegyul_fail_amount_temp == "0":
                            print("conclusion!")
                            self.db_to_all_item(order_num, code, code_name, 0, purchase_price)
                        else:
                            print("less conclusion")
                            self.db_to_all_item(order_num, code, code_name, 1, purchase_price)

                    elif order_gubun == "+buying":
                        if chegyul_fail_amount_temp != "0" and self.stock_chegyul_check(code) == True:
                            print("quantity left, stock_chegyul_check True!")
                            pass
                        elif chegyul_fail_amount_temp == "0" and self.stock_chegyul_check(code) == True:
                            print("no quantity, stock_chegyul_check True!")
                            self.end_invest_count_check(code)
                        elif self.stock_chegyul_check(code) == False:
                            print("repurchase in all db")

                        else:
                            pass
                    elif order_gubun == "-매도":
                        if chegyul_fail_amount_temp == "0":
                            print("all selling in all db!")
                            self.sell_final_check(code)
                        else:
                            print("selling in all db!")
                            self.sell_chegyul_fail_check(code)

                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    print("There is blank in _receive_chejan_data but not bad coed")
            else:
                print("There is bad code in _receive_chejan_data!!")

        elif gubun == "1":
            print("balance data!!!!!")

            chegyul_fail_amount_temp = self.get_chejan_data(902)
            print(chegyul_fail_amount_temp)

        else:
            pass

    def comm_connect(self):
        try:
            self.dynamicCall("CommConnect()")
            time.sleep(TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL)
            self.login_event_loop = QEventLoop()
            self.login_event_loop.exec_()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def _receive_msg(self, sScrNo, sRQName, sTrCode, sMsg):
        print(sMsg)

    def _event_connect(self, err_code):
        try:
            if err_code == 0:
                logger.debug("connected")
            else:
                logger.debug(f"disconnected. err_code : {err_code}")
            self.login_event_loop.exit()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def get_connect_state(self):
        try:
            ret = self.dynamicCall("GetConnectState()")
            time.sleep(TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL)
            return ret
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def set_input_value(self, id, value):
        try:
            self.dynamicCall("SetInputValue(QString, QString)", id, value)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)

    def comm_rq_data(self, rqname, trcode, next, screen_no):

        self.dynamicCall("CommRqData(QString, QString, int, QString)", rqname, trcode, next, screen_no)
        time.sleep(TR_REQ_TIME_INTERVAL)
        self.tr_event_loop = QEventLoop()
        self.tr_event_loop.exec_()

    def _get_comm_data(self, code, field_name, index, item_name):
        ret = self.dynamicCall("GetCommData(QString, QString, int, QString)", code, field_name, index, item_name)
        return ret.strip()

    def _get_repeat_cnt(self, trcode, rqname):
        try:
            ret = self.dynamicCall("GetRepeatCnt(QString, QString)", trcode, rqname)
            return ret
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Openapi()
```

Comment: Is PyCharm definitely using the correct Python, i.e. the one where you have installed PyQt5?
Does your program work if you run it from the command line?

Comment: I downloaded pyqt5 from powershell and also from the terminal inside pycharm. Does this mean the python you mean by installing pyqt5??
And when I checked the list with pip list, pyqt5 exists.